# Main content widget is overlapping with right sidebar

Tags: css, overlap

I'm creating a Blogger theme with Artisteer for the very first time. The problem is I would like to put an ad banner before the post content. I can do that through Blogger dashboard. However, it overlaps the right sidebar. What I want to do is to bring down the sidebar if the ad is on, and if not, for example a visitor is using an "AdBlocker", it will go back to its original position.

Please check a test post [here](http://perorortest1.blogspot.com/2015/01/boracay.html)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably because in your CSS either the banner, or right sidebar are set in a way where they ignore the flow of other elements. At a  quick glance, it appears to be the banner might need some tweaking, but without seeing the code...kinda just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

If the user should use some adblock, no harm there, it should be removed/blocked, and it will probably flow naturally.

For the overlapping issues, looking through your css, you need to add the following:

```
div.peroroblock img{
    max-width: 100%;
}
.peroroblockcontent a{
    display: block;
}
```

These will make sure that if you have a image in your `.peroroblockcontent` it will scale it accordingly to its container.

Answer (score 0):

In your css

Add

```
div.peroroblock img {
    width:100%;
}
```

Then Add

```
.separator a {
    margin:0;
}
```